# In Git, how do I pull from a repository and get all the submodule changesets that are commited in that repository's submodule child repo's?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use [`git submodules`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) with a topology like:

```
parent_repo
`-- child_repo
```

We're maintaining a trunk copy that we all push and pull from. ( I know a star topology is not necessary.  I realize you can pull from each other without reflecting through a central repository.)

```
trunk_child_repo <--+
                    |
trunk_parent_repo   |
`-- child_repo -----+ # child_repo will pull from trunk_child_repo by default
```

Now we have multiple copies of `trunk_parent_repo` with fully-populated submodules.

```
trunk_parent_repo
`-- child_repo

ross_parent_repo
`-- child_repo

bob_parent_repo
`-- child_repo

joe_parent_repo
`-- child_repo
```

I'm in the `ross_parent_repo` and I want to pull from `bob_parent_repo` and get all the edits that bob has done to the files in `bob_parent_repo` *as well as the edits he's committed to his submodule* `bob_parent_repo/child_repo`.

Unfortunately, when I do a `git pull --recurse-submodules bob_parent_repo`, it pulls from `bob_parent_repo` into `ross_parent_repo`, *but `trunk_child_repo` into `ross_parent_repo/child_repo`*.

Is it possible to have a nice, easy command to pull all the changesets that Bob has done in `bob_parent_repo` as well as all the changesets that he has done in all of his submodules?  Will I have to script it up and iterate through the submodules in the `.gitmodules` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to open up `.gitmodules`; you can use `git submodule foreach`.

```
git pull $BOBS_PARENT_REPO
git submodule foreach 'git pull $BOBS_PARENT_REPO/$path/.git'
```

(This won't work for any submodules-of-submodules, though.)

Comment: i think in 1.7.5 you can do recursive foreach with --recursive